# javascript file is not loaded

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a survey page. my HTML code is :

```
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Survey.css" />
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Survey.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
</body>
</html>
```

My body has one div tag and I am calling one function on its click
My js code is:

```
function showHideSurveyForms(int tab_id)
{
alert("abcd");
}
```

All the files are in the same folder. but my js is not loaded(jquery loads successfully). why so?

Comment: Try Chrome's developer tools to see fi there are javascript errors. Also, are you *sure* that your file is named "Survey.js"? :)

Comment: Did you try clearing history/cache, restarting browser? It has helped me in these cases.

Comment: You could also try changing the method in your tag to "<script src="Survey.js" language="JavaScript"></script>"  Sometimes the language is more important than the type.

Comment: type this script name in your address bar like this: http://example.com/Survey.js  to see if it's there. If it gives you error 404 check if the file exists in the same folder as your index html file

Comment: make sure your file is Survey.js and not survery.js.  If you are running on a linux server the files are case sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is not a statically typed language. So you cant use type declaration in the parameters.  Is this what you want? the alert is showing now

```js
function showHideSurveyForms(tab_id)
{
alert("abcd");
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Survey.css" />
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Survey.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
      <div onclick="showHideSurveyForms(this);">CLICK ME</div>
</body>
</html>
```